# Color intensity increases when converting PKDrawing data to uiimage

Tags: swift, canvas, drawing, pencilkit

I am trying to convert PKDrawing data to uiimage. Thus I've used apple's API [PKDrawing data to uiimage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/pkdrawing/3281893-image). But the colour intensity of the converted image increases surprisingly. I mean there is a difference between the canvas data and the converted uiimage. What could be the actual reason behind that?

Here is the scenario

**1. Preview Drawing Data on CanvasView**
[image: Preview Drawing Data on CanvasView]

**2. Preview after converting Drawing Data to uiimage**
[image]

Comment: Noticing this as well. Did you ever find a solution?